# What's the best way to handle landscape/portrait differences in IB?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a view that supports landscape and portrait viewing, with the controls all moving around when you switch from one to the other. I'm currently doing this by setting the .center of each one of my controls when the user rotates the phone. The problem is that this is tedious, and requires a lot of code, and seems to defeat the purpose of using Interface Builder in the first place.

My question is: is there a way in Interface Builder for one view to support multiple looks (one for landscape one for portrait)? If not how do other people do this with IB? Do you set up 2 views?

Edit: Just to clarify my landscape and portrait views look different, I don't want a straight transform, I actually display the data differently in landscape mode

Answer (score 1):

When necessary, I add `UIView` objects to the view in IB which I make hidden.  Give it a nice background color so you can see it, and send it all the way to the background.  Then use that view's frame when you need to set the frame of an object.  If you have a lot of them, you might consider using `UILabel` instead, so you can give it a visible name in IB.

If you're worried about memory issues, just remove all these extra `UIView`s in `ViewDidLoad` and just store their frame values in member `CGRect`s.  This only works of course if you don't have any of the views auto-resize or reposition on rotate, which you probably shouldn't anyway, in this case.  I do this for resizing/repositioning for any reason, not just when the screen rotates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if it's possible, but have you considered using different view controllers for landscape and portrait?

Comment: @Colin: How would that work? On a rotate I would have to drop one and add the other, which I think would do weird things with the screen refresh...it would also mean I'd have to set up some common parent class and try to make them share code...could get very messy

Answer (score 0):

The AutoSize attributes of IBOutlet objects in the Size Inspector of IB (command 3) give some pretty nice options for auto-stretching and positioning of items.  You can control L/R and T/B screen positions and relative width and height.  You can't get full control of the layout, but most of the basic operations are there.

Answer (score 0):

The only way one view can support multiple orientations in IB is to set the autosizing mask of components to either scale and/or anchor to edges. To design a totally different layout for each orientation you need to design a portrait and landscape view separately (each in its own XIB) and switch between them programatically.