# Programming with Interface Builder in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I want to design an application by using Interface Builder, in Landscape mode. I don't know how to put the controls suitable to the Landscape mode. All I know I m rotating my UIView by using self.transform. I am new in it. So can anyone help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is answering your question but you can rotate the views in IB to show in landscape mode by click on the arrow in the top right corner

See the image
[IB landscape](http://www.quicksnapper.com/nduplessis/image/untitled-0000)

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is a bit old, but in Xcode4+ I can't see any rotation arrows.  So instead, open your .xib > go to Simulated Metrics > Orientation > Landscape.  Like this:

[image]

If you can't see the Simulated Metrics option, make sure your view is selected in the object hierarchy:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is (as far as I know) that there is no easy way to do it currently:

[What's the best way to handle landscape/portrait differences in IB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185463/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-landscape-portrait-differences-in-ib)